# One App pool process is crashing and affecting other pool processes

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, application-pool

Under IIS7, I have a website called "MyWebsite" using ASP.Net 2.0, underneath it I have 2 virtual directories: Vdirectory1 using the AppPool1,and Vdirectory2 using the AppPool2.

**Here is what is happening in my environment:**
When the AppPool1 process encounters an exception (I can see an ASP.Net exception in the application log in the event viewer when that happens), the requests that hit Vdirectory2 takes longer than expected (time taken field in the IIS7 logs), they don't crash, they just take longer than expected, which is not good for me.

My understanding is that the ASP.Net 2.0 gets slower in serving other requests, because one process is encountering an exception.

**My Question:**
Is there a way to isolate that? so one Application Pool process wouldn't get affected when another process is encountering an exception?

I hope the situation is clear, if not please let me know and I will do my best to clarify it.

Comment: Each application pool should have it's own separate process, so one should not affect the other.  What makes you think that AppPool1 is affecting AppPool 2?

Comment: which mode are they running in integrated or classic

Comment: when you right click on the Default website in IIS and click on ASP.NET Tab what are the different versions that come up 1.1.x 2.0 etc..? perhaps your 2.0 apps are pointing to 1.1 when the setting should be 2.0 does this make sense

Comment: @Andrew, both the app pools are running integrated mode.

Comment: @DJ I am using IIS 7, so the asp.net version is specified at the app pool level, both app pools are using ASP.Net v2.0.

Comment: I was just asking we use IIS 6.x and 7 and ran into some similar issues maybe its in the IIS App Pool Setting itself have you consulted with your IIS Admin or are you the sole Admin..?

Comment: @CodingGorilla, I suspect that ASP.Net is the one that gets affected in terms of resources availability, it feels like the ASP.Net is **busy** serving that exception, and this is why the other app pool processes get delayed a little bit, I am talking about secs here. Does that make sense?

Comment: ASP.NET is just a set of code libraries that run inside a process.  Since each of the app pools has it's own process, there is nothing they should be sharing in common that would cause one to affect the other.  It's possible that the one work process peg's the cpu or hogs all the memory, which would affect the machine as a whole.  So are there any direct symptoms that leads you to think that AppPool1 is causing a problem with AppPool2?

Comment: You could look at handling exceptions using something like [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) instead of them just being thrown as unhandled.